# OnResponse not working with Volley (reading data from google sheets)

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm new to android so need a little help here. stuck with this problem and tried almost everything in my capacity.

I am trying to simply read some data from google sheets and display it in textViews. (using google sheets as my DataBase)

I am using volley library.

**These are the steps I have already done:**

1. created a project in google developer console and generated APIKey.
2. generated debug keystore
3. added these in my build.gradle(module app):

   implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev9-1.22.0') {
               exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
           }

The problem is: My On Responsenever gets called. the control doesn't go there.and it doesn't show any error. in debug mode,I'm unable to find the error, it simple skips the OnResponse and errorResponse.

**below is my code :**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_math3);
    Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.Button_start);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.show);
    //RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getQuestions();
        }
    });
}
private void getQuestions()
    {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1wut72WqbCv3bAbVGzFaDTYVVf_AJvQAmoVeXrXl81e8/values/Sheet1!A1:C3?key=AIzaSyDalRPlQZkKSwETYlDWJmdA4ut8oB9U_jg";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,new Response.Listener<String>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {

                Log.d("Debug", response);
                parseItems(response);

            }
        },
         new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        int socketTimeOut = 50000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(null);
        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    private void parseItems(String jsonResponse)
    {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("item");


            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
            {

                JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                String Category = jo.getString("Category");
                String Question = jo.getString("Question");
                String Answer = jo.getString("Answer");

                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
                item.put("Category", Category);
                item.put("Question", Question);
                item.put("Answer",Answer);

                list.add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(null,list,R.layout.addition_layout,new String[]{"Category","Question","Answer"},new int[]{R.id.categ,R.id.ques,R.id.ans});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Comment: remove the line `RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(null);
        queue.add(stringRequest);` and move 1`requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
` under `stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);`

Comment: can you solved your problem or not?

Comment: problem still persisting ... the control is not going to onResponse method. I have tested my url with postman and its giving the correct response,but not in android. the app crashes ...

Comment: problem resolved. apparently there was some issue with the permission. i updated the link and its working now. thanks for the support.